# Mandatory apartment inspection

Tags: rental-property, texas, tenant, lease

My apartment in Texas has mandatory unit inspections inside the entire apartment, including water leaks, the smoke detector, the HVAC filter, and electrical outlets, three times a year. Property management enters the apartment with 24-hour notice, regardless of whether the resident is present. I'm not fond of the idea of them entering my apartment when I'm not at home.

Do I have the legitimate right to tell the management not to enter my apartment when I'm not present at the scheduled time?

Answer (score 1):

Texas does not have a statute limiting landlord right to enter the premise, so any limitations on that right would be stated in the lease. If the landlord has a good reason to enter, then they can, and carrying out an inspection is considered a good and valid reason. As noted on [this page](https://texaslawhelp.org/article/tenant-privacy), the standard TAA lease form allows very many reasons to enter, and when the lease does not specify reasons, there is still a right to enter make routine inspections.